# How to get columns titles from googlesheets to print in Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

Basically I'm using Python to pull information off a google spreadsheet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxN8U.png)

I have no problem pulling the information I need but when I start to break it down into specific catergories like "goals scored" i get the information but can print it to the terminal with the column headings. Example below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzICz.png)

So basically I want to bring down the above information but also with the column headings:
'player, position, appearances..... etc'

This is what my code looks like to get the information posted above:

```
data = {
    "man united": SHEET.worksheet("man_utd").get_all_values(),
    "man city": SHEET.worksheet("man_city").get_all_values(),
    "chelsea": SHEET.worksheet('chelsea').get_all_values(),
    "liverpool": SHEET.worksheet('liverpool').get_all_values()
}

team_name = ""
position = ""
top_stats = ""

def user_commands():
    """
    gives commands the user is able to input to receive different data sets
    """
    options = 'Man United, Man City, Liverpool, Chelsea'
    print(f"1: {options}")

    team_name = input("Please Enter A Team Name:\n").casefold()
    print(f"You Have Entered {team_name}\n")

    while team_name not in data:
        print("You Entered a Wrong Option, Please Enter A Correct Option")
        print(f"1: {options}")
        team_name = input()

    print(tabulate(data[team_name]))
    return team_name


def user_commands_2(team_name):

    """
    function to see players of a set position
    from data received from first input.
    Players can be goalkeepers, defenders, midfielders or forwards
    """

    options_1 = 'goalkeeper, defender, midfielder,\nforward, home'
    print(f"1: {options_1}")

    position = input("\nPlease Enter a Position:\n").casefold()
    print(f"You Have Entered {position}\n")

    while position.casefold() not in (options_1):
        print("\nYou Entered a Wrong Option, Please Enter a Correct Option")
        print(f"1: {options_1}")
        position = input()

    if position.casefold() == 'home':
        print("Hi! Welcome to a Football Stats Generator")
        print("The Available Options Are As Follows:")
        main()

    res = [i for i in data[team_name] if position.capitalize() in i]
    print(tabulate(res))

print("Hi! Welcome To a Football Stats Generator\n")

print("The Available Options Are As Follows:\n")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can I ask you about the sample output you expect?

Comment: `data[team_name][0]` should give you the header

Comment: Tanaike, I want the output of the second picture but with the title for those columns also. So like Player on top of column 1, Position on top of column 2 and so on

Comment: idfurw, Yes that worked!! Thanks. So simple, can't believe I didn't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Use "get_all_records()" instead of "get_all_values()".

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.